# Adding a new keyframe while working with dopesheet sets the last keyframe to the current

Tags: keyframes, dopesheet

So I have a problem were I add a new keyframe in between a loop the last keyframe takes the new keyframe's value.

Lets say I have :

- keyframe 1: x=0
- keyframe 2: x=16

and then I add

- keyframe 3: x=6

in between. What happens then is that keyframe 2 value changes to 6? I have been searching to modify this behaviour everywhere, but don't seem to be able, any help?

Comment: Just to double check, you do deselect before adding the new one, right?